# Bash for loop end condition given as script argument

Tags: bash, for-loop

I'm using this script to copy virtual machines in my ESXI 6.5. The first argument of the script is the name of the directory to copy.

I would like to have a second argument, which would be the number of vms I want to copy. For now on, I need to modify the for loop every time I want to copy different number of vms. The below script creates 20 vms by copying the directory of a vm given as the first script argument. I run it like this: `./copy.sh CentOS1` but would like to have something like this: `./copy.sh CentOS1 x` where x is the end condition in my for loop.

```
#!/bin/sh

for i in $(seq 1 1 20)
do 
    mkdir ./$1_$i/
    cp $1/* $1_$i/
    echo "Copying machine '$1_$i' ... DONE!"
done
```

**NOTE:** Please do not suggest other for solutions, like those given, for instance, here: https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/bash-for-loop/ because I checked them and they didn't work.

Thanks.

Comment: you mean `$(seq 1 1 $2)`? or you could even supply a default value as `$(seq 1 1 ${2:-20})`

Comment: Don't worry; the link you provide is full of terrible advice and examples.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a C-style `for` loop, if you are using `bash`.

```
for ((i=1; i<=$2; i++))
do 
    mkdir "./$1_$i/"
    cp "$1"/* "$1_$i/"
    echo "Copying machine '$1_$i' ... DONE!"
done
```

If you need POSIX compatibility (as implied by your shebang), then you probably can't rely on `seq` being available either; use a `while` loop.

```
i=1
while [ "$i" -le "$2" ]; do
    mkdir ./"$1_$i"
    cp "$1"/* "$1_$i"
    i=$((i+1))
done
```

Comment: if you don't have `for (( ))` then you don't have  `$(( ))` either; replace increment with `let i=i+1` or `i=\`expr $i + 1\``. But it's old syntax.

Comment: @EdouardThiel Yes, you do. `$((...))` is [part of the POSIX standard](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_06_04). `let` is a `bash` extension, and `i=$(expr $i + 1)` is perfectly valid but inefficient (since it spawns an external process instead of performing the arithmetic in the shell itself).

Answer (score 1):

In spite of your protestations to the contrary, one of the solutions in your link would work fine:

```
for ((i=1; i<=$2; i++)); do
    # body of loop goes here
done
```

would loop from 1 to the number given in the second argument

Comment: ESXI shell gives `line 2: syntax error: bad for loop variable`

Comment: @Katie I'm not sure what shell ESXi uses, but I'm betting it's not `bash`, it's probably something that tries to be a POSIX shell, like `sh` or `dash` or similar would be my guess.  Assuming that's the case, use the portable solution from chepner